# Matrix allocation in one line

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, matrix

Watching some code found on internet I came across this piece of code:

```
int (*p)[3];

p = (int(*)[3]) calloc(5*3,sizeof(int));
```

is it just a way to alloc a matrix?

I understand that `int (*p)[3]` creates a pointer to an array of 3 int, but I'm not sure about the `calloc` call: I know that `calloc` allocate and initialize a number of `int` (in this case) equal to the first parameter (`5*3`).
Thus, if I assign it to `p` it should mean that the pointer now points to the just allocated memory location.

So, since I know my reasoning is wrong, may somebody correct me?

Comment: `calloc(m,n)` allocates and zeroes out `m*n` bytes of memory, not `m`.

Comment: Yes, I meant it allocates 5*3 `int`. I corrected my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int (*p)[3];
```

You're true that this is a pointer to an array of three ints, but this pointer could also point to the beginning of **an array of arrays** of three ints.

```
p = (int(*)[3]) calloc(5*3,sizeof(int));
```

Here, you allocate 5 * 3 ints to this pointer. As `int[3]` has 3 ints, you just allocated 5 such `int[3]` arrays.

You may then refer to these `int[3]` arrays as

`p[0]` ... `p[4]`

so you get a two-dimensional array ranging

`p[0][0]` ... `p[0][2]`

`p[4][0]` ... `p[4][2]`

Comment: So, since `calloc` allocates 15 `int`s, and I get a 5*3 matrix, where do the original three `int`s end up? Are they just thrown away? If yes, what is the need to allocate them? Why we can't declare `int **p`?

Comment: @user1372813 There are no original three ints before you call `calloc`. `int (*p)[3];` is just a declaration - it creates the pointer p that may point to `int[3]`. However, until you initialize this pointer, like `p = &somearray` or `p = (int(*)[3]) malloc (...)`, it points to some random place in the memory.

Comment: @user1372813 Also, you can't just declare `**p`. The declaration `int (*p)[3];` tells the compiler that the second dimension of the matrix is `3`. So if you write, for example, `p[1][2]` you get the value `*(p + 1 * 3 + 2)`. Without this information, the compiler would not know how to interpret `p[1][2]` because it wouldn't know how long the first row, `p[0]`, is.

Comment: Oh yes, now I see! Thank you very much! So, this way, to release the memory we just to call `free(p)`, isn't it?

Comment: @user1372813 Yes. You allocated your array by a single `calloc` call, so you can release it by a single `free` call.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is correct.  `calloc` allocates and zeros enough contiguous memory to hold 15 `int`s, and returns a pointer to the beginning of it.